# Catching errors with ES6 promises and BookshelfJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, es6-promise, bookshelf.js

I'm adding a very basic login method to a Bookshelf User model in an ExpressJS app, but I can't catch the errors from the rejected promise that the login function in the User model returns. I'm looking at Bookshelf's example login in the docs at http://bookshelfjs.org/#Model-static-extend but that example uses Bluebird, whereas I'm trying to do the same with the built-in ES6 promises.

My login method in the User model:

*userModel.js*

```
function login(email, password) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    User.where('email', email)
      .fetch({ require: true })
      .then(user => {
        bcrypt.compare(password, user.get('password'), (err, matched) => {
          if (!matched) return reject(new Error('Password didn\'t match!'));
          resolve(user);
        });
      });
  });
```

The controller action that implements login and calls `User.login` from the Bookshelf `User` model:

*usersAuthController.js*

```
function logUserIn(req, res) {
  new User().login(req.body.email, req.body.password)
    .then(user => res.json({ message: 'Login succeeded!' }))
    .catch(User.NotFoundError, () => res.status(404).json({ error: 'User not found!' }) // catch #1
    .catch(err => res.status(401).json({ err: err.message })); // catch #2
}
```

My intention is that `login()` can return a rejected promise when Bookshelf's [`User.fetch`](http://bookshelfjs.org/#Model-instance-fetch) method can't find the user with the given email. In that case, the `.catch(User.NotFoundError ...)` (catch #1) line should catch it and return a 404. I also intend `login()` to return a rejected Promise when `bcrypt` determines that the password passed to `login()` doesn't match the user's password, in which case the "catch-all" (catch #2) below the `User.NotFoundError` catch statement should return a 401.

If I put in the incorrect password, the `logUserIn()` controller action in the above code goes to catch #2 with the error message `{ error: "Cannot set property 'message' of undefined" }` instead of the message `'Password didn't match!'` message that I rejected in `login()`. If I put in a nonexistent email, the response is never sent and the error `Unhandled rejection CustomError: EmptyResponse` is thrown in the console. Only valid input works.

**An attempt at fix:** catching `User.NotFoundError` directly in the model instead.

I moved catch #1 to the User model so that the login method now looks like:

*userModel.js*

```
function login(email, password) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    User.where('email', email)
      .fetch({ require: true })
      .then(user => {
        bcrypt.compare(password, user.get('password'), (err, matched) => {
          if (!matched) return reject(new Error('Password didn\'t match!'));
          resolve(user);
        });
      })
      .catch(User.NotFoundError, () => reject({ error: 'User not found!' }));
  });
```

This way, I can catch both errors (incorrect password and nonexistent email) correctly, but this way I can't specify the status code in the controller. If the user with the given email couldn't be found, then it should return a 404, but if the password was incorrect, then it should return a 401, but both errors go to the catch-all (catch #2) in the controller action (which always returns a 401).

To solve this problem, in the `User` model I could do `.catch(User.NotFoundError, () => reject({ name: 'NotFoundError', message: 'User not found!' }))` and in the controller action I can check for what kind of error I'm getting with `const statusCode = err.name === 'NotFoundError' ? 404 : 401` but that seems really messy and misses the point of having these `.catch` statements.

Is there a way to catch the `User.NotFoundError` from the model's login method and any other errors all in `logInUser`? Why doesn't the setup I had at first work, the one with both `catch` statements in usersAuthController.js, and what did the `Cannot set property 'message' of undefined'` and `CustomError: EmptyResponse` errors mean (does it have something to do with mixing up Bookshelf's Bluebird promises versus the built-in ES6 promises)? What's the best way to handle this?

Comment: Avoid the [`Promise` constructor antipattern](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572)! You should only promisify `bcrypt.compare` in that  `login` function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your initial implementation, you're not propagating any rejections that may be caused by `User.fetch()`. Also, because `User.fetch()` already returns a promise, wrapping it with a new promise is a bit of an anti-pattern (although you still need to wrap `bcrypt.compare()` with a promise, since that only works with callbacks).

Try this:

```
function login(email, password) {
  return User .where('email', email)
              .fetch({ require: true })
              .then(user => {
                return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                  bcrypt.compare(password, user.get('password'), (err, matched) => {
                    if (err)      return reject(err);
                    if (!matched) return reject(new Error('Password didn\'t match!'));
                    resolve(user);
                  });
                })
              });
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Just to clarify, usually when should I wrap stuff in a Promise (if I get this, is the point of returning the Promise in `.then` is so that I can chain the `.then`s)?

Comment: @satray if something already returns a promise, you don't have to wrap it. In this case, because `bcrypt.compare` doesn't return a promise, it gets wrapped (but "as late as possible"). It's always a good thing to return promises (and promise chains), even if you handle `.then()` and `.catch()` already.